# Backbone try to update model in server after save

Tags: backbone.js, ruby-on-rails-4

I use Rails 4 + backbone in my application.

Everything is good. New model is created in backbone and saved by calling:

```
newItem.save(null, {success: this.sendSuccess, error: this.sendError});
```

However, implementing a new feature I need to change one of the model attributes. What I see that a `PUT` action is fired just before `sendSuccess` is called, which I want to avoid.

Moreover, the url is very strange. Save action calls this url:

```
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:3000
Request URL:http://www.lvh.me:3000/api/user/1/tickets
Request Method:POST
```

and then, after server return the json with the modified attribute, backbone calls this url:

```
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:3000
Request URL:http://www.lvh.me:3000/api/user/1/tickets
Request Method:PUT
```

without the ticket id!

Is there any way to prevent backbone fire an **update** when server return the model with different attributes?

Comment: Any chance your code calls `model.save` in response to a `"change"` event?

Comment: Yes, this was the problem, thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had a listener in my model exactly on the column that server changed:

```
initialize: function() {
  this.on("change:status", this.statusChanged, this);
},
```

Now I had to figure out why the update url does not contain the model id.

I figured out that when I first created the model, from some reasons I couldn't assign it to the collection, so in order to save it I assign the url manually:

```
var newTicket = new MyApp.Ticket( ticketData );
newTicket.url = this.collection.url();
```

Now, the bug is that url is a function, and I simply overrided it!

I changed the code to:

```
newTicket.urlRoot = this.collection.url();
```

and now it works.

Answer (score -1):

Backbone will always perform PUT if your model has an id attribute setted. Which makes sense when using RESTfull.

Be sure that you're really SAVING(new model withoud an ID) a data to server instead of UPDATING(model with an ID) to server.